# How many ways are there to remove $2 \times 2$ rooms from $n \times m$ bounded grid by building walls

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, algorithms

On an $n\times m$ grid, a room is considered to be a $2\times 2$ subgrid such that there isn't a wall between any $2$ cells in that subgrid that share an edge.

Initially, there are no walls in the grid, except its perimeter (outer boundary).
You are allowed to build any number of walls of length $1$. In other words, one side of any unit square can become a wall.

How many ways are there to build any number of walls such that there are no rooms left in the grid?

I think this is a variant of a more general problem:

In a graph $G$, how many ways are there to pick any number of edges such that every vertex of $G$ has a degree of at least $1$?
It's similar because we consider grid points as vertices and lines between them as edges, so a point without an edge going out of it is a room.

This more general problem might be NP hard, but it's often the case that NP problems on graphs can be solved in polynomial time on grid graphs.

My tries:
I highly doubt that there exists a closed formula.
Best what I thought of for this problem is $O (n*m*2^{\min(n, m)})$ complexity.

The challenging part is when dealing with transition from $n \times m-1$ to $n \times m$, because we don't know which vertices already have an edge, and which we have to deal with in the new row. Let's call the sequence of bits that represent which vertices are already satisfied, a profile of a row (there are $2^n$ distinct profiles). Now for every profile it's counted differently. Maybe it's possible to instead look only at the count of vertices that are already satisfied, but I didn't get anywhere with that idea.

Comment: I couldn't follow the first two paragraphs, but the more general problems with the graphs seems to just refer to [edge covers](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edge_cover), no? Like you, I doubt that enumerating edge covers is easy let alone having a closed form.

Comment: @JeroenvanderMeer Thanks for the answer. To simplify my problem, it's basically enumerating edge covers of n*m [grid graphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_graph). As I mentioned, many problems that are very hard on general graphs are much easier on grids, so I thought it might be the same for this problem. I guess [this](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/21279/complexity-of-counting-the-number-of-edge-covers-of-a-graph) answers my question (it's p-complete, even for regular graphs).

Comment: I see, thanks for confirming. For grid graphs, the number of edge covers is enumerated in OEIS sequence [A286912](https://oeis.org/A286912). It doesn't seem to tell us how these numbers were obtained however.